# How to pass Dynamic Parameters to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have designed my layout completely dynamic based upon a table's columns.  Suppose when the user adds a new column in a table, then without modifying any logic it will show that column on the page.

As far selection it's working fine. But I facing hurdle in saving data in the database.

How I can save this data, because I do not specify the parameter in stored procedure that will fulfill my requirement. I want to pass it dynamically.

Comment: can you provide more details on what exactly do you require. Based on limited information in your question, you could get the list of columns in a table dynamically and create an appropriate insert/update statement within the application.

Comment: currently my table have 5 columns, my Report.aspx all the table's column render on page as textbox , where user can enter the value, now I want to save these in sql server through Store procedure. 
NOW If I Add one more Column in Table, Then my I do not want to write any type of code in any side like not on page/not on Stored Procedure. If table's field increase/decrease then my page still work smoothly that's my task.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `TABLE` parameter to the stored procedure. So you can create a table type something like this

```
 CREATE TYPE LIST_OF_PARAMS AS TABLE (id int, NAME VARCHAR)
```

then you have to alter your procedure to accept a variable of type LIST_OF_PARAMS.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE LIST_OF_PARAMS AS TABLE (id int, NAME VARCHAR) 
go 
CREATE PROCEDURE Myproc @Mytable LIST_OF_PARAMS READONLY,
                       @id     INT
AS
  BEGIN
```

Also note that:

> Note that in **SQL Server 2008 table valued parameters are read only**.
>   But as you notice we actually require you to write READONLY. So that
>   actually then means that at some point in the future maybe if you say
>   please, please please often enough we might be able to actually make
>   them writable as well at some point. But at the moment they are read
>   only.

Comment: CREATE TYPE LIST_OF_PARAMS AS TABLE (id int),
you mean i have to defined all the table's column here like (Id int) ?

If that's true , then how does it call dynamic ?

Comment: @GREESHKUMAR:- You can add id int or varchar. Whatever type of values you have. I have added a sample code for reference

Comment: Sorry this will not resolve my issue, 

currently my table have 5 columns, my Report.aspx all the table's column render on page as textbox , where user can enter the value, now I want to save these in sql server through Store procedure. NOW If I Add one more Column in Table, Then my I do not want to write any type of code in any side like not on page/not on Stored Procedure. If table's field increase/decrease then my page still work smoothly that's my task. –

Comment: @GREESHKUMAR:- Then I am afraid you have to look for some other alternatives as I dont think there is any way to achive what you are saying with the SQL.